# Unconventional to bundle web socket server with REST API?

Tags: api, rest, websocket

For an enterprise REST API (PHP in this case), is it a bad practice to include a web socket server along with a REST API? The pairing of the two makes a nice mix with event dispatching services, but I'm not sure if these two services are different enough where they warrant separation? I guess the only con I can see at the moment, would be that if the REST API were to go down, then your web socket servers are also down, which removes the possibility of having fail-over for any connected clients, or something to that degree.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a really robust way to manage web sockets, check out http://faye.jcoglan.com/ - it has libraries for JavaScript, Ruby, etc, and runs independently of your other servers.

If you don't need that kind of resilience, then I wouldn't worry about mixing your REST and web socket APIs on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm not searching for a web sockets impl... I know there are a lot of great options to choose from, but that's a different task for a different day. What I'm wondering is, whether the web socket server should reside in the same module as my RESTful web service, or if the two should exist independently, and I should use a message queue protocol to dispatch messages to the web sockets module (to pub updates) - (as opposed to native event dispatching, in a scenario where the two are actually bundled as one).